# QGIS Polyons/Lines to Autocad Polylines with thickness

Tags: qgis, autocad

I have a file with polygons representing building areas and an attribute table with a column for building height, I want to export to dxf polylines with the property "Thickness" filled in with the building height. Anyone can help me on how to do this in qgis? I know I can convert the polygons to lines in qgis and export to dxf and have it show as polylines but the attribute does not carry over.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to [export your shape to `DWG`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#create-dxf-files), or use the AutoCAD-addon `spatial manager` in order to import the shapefile with its attributes to CAD.